# Convert String date to util date and insert in sql date

Tags: java, jsp, date

So I have few files in the first submit file

List.jsp

```
<input type="hidden" name="date"  value='<fmt:formatDate value="${b.datePub}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"/>'/>         
<input type="submit" value="Edit"></form>
```

List2.jsp

```
<br/> Date Published (mm/dd/yyyy) [READ]: 
<input type="text" name="datePub"  value='<fmt:formatDate value="${datePub}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"/>' readonly="readonly"/>
```

dao.java

```
....
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date d= sdf.parse(request.getParameter("datePub"));
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime());
insert.setDate(5, sqlDate);
....
```

The error I got was `javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert 01/01/2000 of type class java.lang.String to class java.util.Date` I have been trying to figure out the problem for quite awhile now. Can someone spot where the problem is?

Comment: wich line raises the error?

Comment: it doesn't say in the error message. http://pastebin.com/Xmdm0iPm

Comment: I really do belive it crashes in `List2.jsp`... It looks like `${datePub}` is a string and the format tag should be feeded a date object

Comment: well... as for the stacktrace reads `org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.edit_jsp._jspx_meth_fmt_005fformatDate_005f0(edit_jsp.java:203)`. It looks like the same case I wrote you before but in another file. You´re trying to write/format a string when it should be a date.

Comment: I dont have file called edit_jsp.java

Comment: It is in the stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Instead
<input type="text" name="datePub"  value='<fmt:formatDate value="${datePub}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy>' readonly="readonly"/>
```

It should be

```
<input type="text" name="datePub"  value='<c:out value="${datePub}"/>' readonly="readonly"/>
```

Because putting second formatDate which already formated will cause it to read as string where it is a date.